# CakePHP install in a folder, not root

Tags: cakephp

In CakePHP documentation we can see this part : http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation.html#development but it's wrong ! i put cakephp in a folder named /test and nothing works like documentation says... i don't touch any files. I can't touch the apache configuration because i use gandi simple hosting https://www.gandi.net/hebergement/simple. how can i resolve that ? I need to edit .htaccess ?

Comment: When you say "nothing works", what do you see actually? A screenshot or error message is great in helping the community to help you debug the problem.

Comment: CakePHP works out of the box on any location, except if you didn't follow the best practices and you can end up with some errors. Try to enable debug (from /Config/core.php) set it to 2, see what it prints. Also see the logs under {project_root}/app/tmp/logs

Comment: no errors, it's works fine in root directory but not with a subfolder.

Answer (score 0):

By default your website is loaded from public_html folder. If you create a website under a sub-folder and you want to display it when you type the domain name. In most cake applications it should be /cake/app/webroot.

In your public_html folder you will need an .htaccess something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !folder/
RewriteRule (.*) /folder/app/webroot/$1 [L]
```

Remember you can also have your Cake files outside your public_html folder and simply specify the cake path in your webroot/index.php

Comment: You will need to check your error logs. This should tell you why it is giving a blank page.

Comment: Sorry, Above code is redirecting all the traffic to that /folder and disturbing the site in root. :(